# Symfony 4 file controller helper how to convert binary file to HTML compatible?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Trying to retrieve an image from outside `public`. I have been using `file controller helper` but still can't get it to work:

here is my code that is returned as `AJAX` to update the `IMG SRC` path

```
$imgPATH = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir').'/uploads/user_profile_pictures/';

$ext = [".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif"];

foreach ($ext as $x) {
    $imgPath = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir').'/uploads/user_profile_pictures/'.$usertoPic.$x;

    if (file_exists($imgPath)) {
       return $this->file($imgPath , 'userProfilePicture.png' , ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE);
    } 
}
```

The image is found by PHP but I get the following broken `HTML` in the browser; I think this is because it is binary ? how can I convert it to HTML compliant ?

```
<img id="userIMG" src="�PNG��IHDR���S���S���lЬW���pHYs��.#��.#x�v��OiCCPPhotoshop ICC profile��xڝSgTS�=���BK���KoR RB���&amp;*!J�!��Q�EEȠ�����Q,������������{�kּ������&gt;�����H3Q5��B�������.@�$p��d!s�#��~&lt;&lt;+&quot;���x���M��0���B�\���t�8K��@z�B��@F���&amp;S���`�cb��P-�`" �������{�[�!���="" e�d�h;���v�e�x0�fk�9��-�0iwfh��������="" �0q��)�{�`�##x����f�w<�+��*��x��<�$9e�[-qww.(�i+6aa�@.�y�2�4�����������x����6��_-��"bb���ϫp@���t~��,="" ��;�m��%�h^�u��f�@�����w�p�~<<e���������j�b[a�w}�g�_�w�l�~<�����$�2]�g�����l�ϒ="" �b��g�����"�ib�x*�qq�d���2�"�b�)�%��d��,�="">
```

Comment: Which web-server do you use? This is something related to web-server setup. Files outside public directory (`document root` is probably a better term) are not meant to be accessible the way you expect them to be.

Comment: You would first need to put the kernel path "%kernel_root_dir%"

Comment: @FlorentDestremau do you mean like this ? `$imgPATH = '%kernel_root_dir%/uploads/user_profile_pictures/img.png';`

Comment: Symfony 3 version but the concept should be same. [Uploading images to a private directory and serving them in twig template](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/kgcu/uploading-images-to-a-private-directory-and-serving-them-in-twig-template)

Comment: @BentCoder thanks for the link but the first thing is to change user permissions... can't really do that on a development server `composer require server` That would mean I can't test before production ? there must be a more straightforward way

Comment: @Sam comething like that with maybe a "../.." or so in between did it work ?

Comment: @FlorentDestremau I got the correct link in my comment of tsv answer below but the view is not displaying it. twig finds it, php finds it but I get 404 in the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser cannot have access to a file that is not in the `public` (for Symfony 4) folder. That is pretty much the whole point of having a "public" directory.

What you *can* do is serving the file directly as a binary response given a certain link in your app, like documented here:
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-file-controller-helper

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ImgController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/get-my-img")
     */
    public function getImg()
    {
        $basePath = $this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/uploads/user_profile_pictures/';

        return $this->file($basePath . "img.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I tried but still getting 404; I updated my question with the code

Comment: oh it's ajax ? Then replace the `src` field of your image with the url, you're not supposed to fetch the data directly through ajax

Comment: I finally got it working but had to adapt your answer by converting to base64

Comment: Oh right, and then you decode it and set it as `data://blob-xxx..` ?

Comment: I get the file with `$this->getParameter` then encode the file to base64 then set the image src with it. It works because this is an image; not sure about other files.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // this should work quite simple:

    // site/public/css/style.css
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />

    // site/upload/favicon.ico
    <img src="{{ asset('../upload/favicon.ico') }}" />




    $target_dir = '/upload/favicon.ico'; // param in config

    $file = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . $target_dir;
    if(is_file($file)) dump('found: ' . $file);
```

Comment: `$file = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . $target_dir;` is giving me the correct path but symfony is not displaying it. `404` error.  I also tried `<img src="{{ asset('../upload/favicon.ico') }}" />`; twig finds it but the view this is also not displaying it also; the `...` seem to have disappeared and I get `404` with a path starting from public. So it seems that the controller works but not the view. I also tried to use the asset manager without any effect